# QPdfBookmarkModel как получить все оглавления?

Tags: pdf, qt6

Если получить оглавление документа pdf с помощью `QPdfBookmarkModel` и вызвать методы rowCount и columnCount, то columnCount возвратит 1, а rowCount количество глав первого уровня, но если  вставить на форму TreeView и задать этот `QPdfBookmarkModel` как модель, методом `setModel`, то `TreeView` покажет все оглавление, со всеми уровнями.

Вопрос: как получить из `QPdfBookmarkModel` все оглавление без TreeView?

Comment: Спасибо, именно так все и работает, этот комментарий надо ответом сделать

Answer (score 0):

Обычно неявный корневой элемент это простой `QModelIndex()`, соответственно, чтобы получить его дочерние элементы (которые уже должны быть видимыми) надо вызвать метод модели `index()` и передать в него `QModelIndex()`.

Дочерние элементы, в свою очередь, снова передать в тот же метод и получить их дочерние и так далее.

Чтобы узнать количество дочерних элементов надо взывать `rowCount(...)` с соответствующим родительским `QModelIndex`. В общем-то, ничего сложного